# React native unexpected error has ocurred

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

first time using react native. When i run npm start and open the localhost, it says "An unexpected error has ocurred". If i scan the QR code in the Expo app, it says "Something went wrong. Network responde timed out".

When i open the console this appears

[image]

I created the app as:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
expo init MyApp
Selected the typescript template
And then at the MyApp folder npm start
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its probably because of *new version* of expo-cli@5.4.10

Uninstall new version and install 5.4.7

***For npm:***

```
npm -g uninstall expo-cli
npm -g install expo-cli@5.4.7
```

***For yarn:***

```
yarn global remove expo-cli
yarn global add expo-cli@5.4.7
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But for some reason i can't connect my phone to it, it says "Failed to connect to /192.168.0.29 (port 19000) from /192.168.0.122 (port 47250) after 10000ms". Do you know how can i fix it?

Comment: I think its network problem, network of pc and phone should be same. And also it can be a problem of firewall.